# Should I use in, on or at for locations like this: "I am {on/at/in} the railway station"?

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

Which prepositions are correct?

> I am {on/at/in} the railway station.
>   I am {on/at/in} square.

Comment: What is "square"? A square like a courtyard or plaza?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am **on** the railway station.

means you are *on top of* the railway station (like on the ceiling). Not likely.

> I am **at** the railway station.

means you are there, location wise.

> I am **in** the railway station.

means you are inside (the perimeter) of the railway station.

Comment: From the perspective of location, you've described what the three prepositions generally mean, although it's worth pointing out there are numerous idiosyncrasies, anomalies, idiomatic usages, and exceptions, particularly with _on_. "I am on the phone" probably doesn't mean you are on top of it, and "I am on the radio" doesn't usually mean you are on top of it either.